# Loading dump file; VS doesn't find my source code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols, minidump

I'm developing a .NET 4.0 app in VS 2010.

I'm trying to use dump files for the first time, but when loading the minidump into VS, I can't debug it, since VS doesn't find the source files.

Here's what I did:

- In `Options -> Debugging -> Symbols` I added my app's build dir, which contains the pdbs.
- Ran the app in the VS debugger. Selected `Debug -> Break All`.
- Selected `Debug -> Save dump as`
- Went to the dump file in windows explorer and opened it. This opened a new instance of VS.
- I clicked "Debug with mixed". This opened a new tab that said `"There is no source code available for the current location`.

I tried to figure out why VS wasn't loading my pdbs:

- Opened `Debug -> Windows -> Modules`
- The `Symbol Status` column for MyApp.exe said "Symbols loaded".
- For MyApp.vshost.exe it said "Cannot find or locate the PDB file".
- Rightclicked on MyApp.exe, selected "Symbol load info". It said "MyApp.pdb: Symbols loaded."
- Did the same for MyApp.vshost.exe. It said *vshost32.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.*. **(note how it's looking for a file named vshost32.pdb rather than MyApp.vshost.pdb, for some reason)**

So, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem. VS was looking at the bottom-most method in the call-stack, which was a system method somewhere in ntdll.dll. So naturally there was no source for it. I had to click on my own method in the `Call Stack` window to navigate to my own code, for which source *was* available.

Comment: Adding build director in the Option->Debugging->Symbols solved my problem of no source code available !